# How to specify an optional regex group with a newline character in checkstyle's RegexpHeader?

Tags: java, regex, maven, checkstyle

I'm having trouble specifying a regex group (`()?`) containing a newline character (`\n`) in the `RegexpHeader` module of the `maven-checkstyle-plugin`, e.g.

```
<module name="Checker">
    <module name="RegexpHeader">
        <property
            name="header"
            value="a\nb"/>
        <property name="fileExtensions" value="java"/>
    </module>
</module>
```

where as `value="a(\nc)?b"` fails with error `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (check_style) on project document-scanner: Failed during checkstyle configuration: cannot initialize module RegexpHeader - Cannot set property 'header' to 'a(\nc)?b' in module RegexpHeader: InvocationTargetException: line 1 in header specification is not a regular expression -> [Help 1]`.

According to the [RegexpHeader docs](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_header.html)

> Individual header lines must be separated by the string "\n"

Which explains that the regex causes an error, yet it prevents specification of regular expressions with optional groups containing a newline character. Examples for this case are also not specified.

Solutions which don't work:

- Replacing `\n` with `\\n` and `\\\n` doesn't work (causes the same error as above).
- `value="/*a(\x10c)?b*/\n"` matches a file starting with

  ```
  /*ab*/
  bla bla
  ```

  but not

  ```
  /*a
  cb*/
  bla bla
  ```
- adding plain newlines in the `checkstyle` XML file
- adding `&#10;` or `\x0A` for newline characters

`value="/\*a&#10;cb\*/\n"` matches

```
/*a
cb*/
bla bla
```

so it seem to be the regex control characters (`()?`) which are causing trouble.

I'm using the `maven-checkstyle-plugin` 2.17 and Java 7.

I created https://github.com/krichter722/maven-checkstyle-plugin-multiline in order to facilitate investigating.

Comment: I have not come across checkstyle before but from what I have just looked into think its not possible to do it the way you are trying. Have you considered [RegexpMultiline](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_regexp.html#RegexpMultiline) and see if it works for you?

Comment: That is hard because `checkstyle` only allows to specify an illegal pattern and negating regex pattern is overly hard in Java. I've suggested to add a flag to control whether a multiline pattern is legal or illegal some time ago (https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/1166) and now have the example requested by the developers to deal with the issue (I'll post it in the issue tracker).

Comment: Try this `value="a(\x10c)?b"`

Comment: It matches if the optional group isn't present, but not if it is (see edited question).

Comment: The numerical value of the linefeed character is 10 *decimal*; the hexadecimal escape would be `\x0A`.

Comment: I'm not sure of what you're saying. Xml attribute value strings are parsed as literals, not strings. In other words, `atr="val\"`ue" will give atr the value of `val\ `. So, the xml parsing isn't the problem. After parsing, the string `a\nb` is in the hands of whatever is parsing the xml. But by that time `a\nb` is in a string variable. If `\n` is used as a delimiter to something else, you only have the option of expressing it as hex or octal, both sequences of which start with an escape.

Answer (score 1):

Try a multiline mode where `^` and `$` match start/end of *each line*:

```
(?m)a($\s+^c)?b
```

You may have to experiment a bit with how to code the backslash.

Comment: Pure `&&` fails because XML can't be parsed. Escaping doesn't lead to the desired result. `/\*a([\s&amp;&amp;[^ \t]]c)?b\*/\n` fails like non-working solutions listed above (non-present optional group passes, presence causes failure).

Comment: @KarlRichter this is quite a puzzler... Try my new attempt.

Comment: Agreed. `$\s+^` doesn't make sense for me because there can be nothing between line and start of the following, right? I tried `(?m)a($^c)?b` and a file without `/*` and `*/` which isn't valid Java, but that shouldn't matter which doesn't work.

Comment: @KarlRichter:  `$` and `^` are zero-width assertions, meaning neither of them will consume the newline.  So `$^` will never match, because there has to be at least one newline character separating lines.  `\s+` matches any whitespace characters, and putting anchors around it insures that there's at least one newline among them.

Comment: Adding `\s+` between `$` and `^` doesn't help. Thanks for you input so far.

Answer (score 0):

I found some problems with how you're trying to use regexes. I think I also found a solution (but I am unable to test it because I don't use Maven/Checkstyle).

---

Your hypothesis about `()?` being the issue is wrong. Scrolling down the page for RegexpHeader, there is an example that uses a regex group like `()?`:

```
<module name="RegexpHeader">
  <property
    name="header"
    value="^// Copyright (\d\d\d\d -)? 2004 MyCompany$\n^// All rights reserved$"/>
</module>
```

---

There is a problem with your regex here: `value="/*a(\x10c)?b*/\n"`. You're not escaping the regex control characters (but not the ones you pointed out). You should make it:

```
value="/\\*a(\x10c)?b\\*/\n"
```

In Java, it is necessary to have the "evil" escaped escape (`\\`). The regex in its pure form is:

```
 /\*a(\x10c)?b\*/\n
```

You can use the "pure form" when the regex is in its own file.

The full text from the docs states (emphasis mine):

> the required header specified inline. Individual header lines must be separated by the string "\n" (even on platforms with a different line separator), and **regular expressions must *not* span multiple lines**.

This might mean that you are required to prefix each line with the anchor `^`. All the examples I saw were like that.

You might be wondering how you will be able to use regexes with Javadocs (for example), which fit the following format (roughly):

```
/*
 * line
 */
```

The middle line may be missing. Or there may be 500 lines like that.

They give an example of a header that deals with this.

### Regex file (excerpt):

```
line 12: ^/\*\*
line 13: ^ \*([^/]|$)
line 14: ^ \*/
```

Note: The words `line ##` probably aren't in the file.

### RegexpHeader:

```
<module name="RegexpHeader">
    <property name="headerFile" value="config/java.header"/>
    <property name="multiLines" value="10, 13"/>
</module>
```

See how they have line 13 as "multiline"? From the doc:

> line numbers to repeat (zero or more times)